# Cannot access the jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've downloaded the jquery file. Also, I've put it before my header. But the browser kept telling me that the jquery is not defined. 
By using some testing codes, it showed that the jquery library is not found.

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html　（This is where I downloaded the jquery file.）

PS: I'm a real newbie in this field. This is the first time I try to use jQuery. If the jQuery can be accessed, should I write "$(function() {
  $('selectors').balloon(options);
});"  in the HTML?

This is my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.balloon.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(typeof jQuery !='undefined')
    {
        alert("jQuery library is loaded!"); 
    }else{
        alert("jQuery library is not found!");
    }
</script>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: maybe your source is not correct

Comment: Link on your website pls. Maybe, You try call JQ function before 
library loading

Comment: Questions asking us for debugging help without including the code are off-topic and will get closed

Comment: Looks like you might be pulling in a jQuery *plugin*, but not jQuery itself. Try loading it with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Michael  I'm so sorry. This is the first time I used this page. And I didn't know how to post with my codes.

Comment: This is my code
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.balloon.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         if(typeof jQuery !='undefined'){
 
         alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
 
          }else{
 
      alert("jQuery library is not found!");
     }

Comment: No problem, when you scroll to the bottom of the page you'll see a link 'help'. Make sure to read it and post your questions according to the guidelines, then you'll get great answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the script that you loaded to your page is not jquery at all. It is a jquery plugin, which needs jquery itself.

You can download the real jquery here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: You've found out the main problem. And I've solved it.  One more question, should I call $(function() { $('selectors').balloon(options); }) on my HTML?

Comment: ^ Scroll to bottom of that site and look for examples on using it. After including jquery and this plugin, you can use it like - `$('.sample7-1').balloon({
  tipSize: 24,
  css: {
    backgroundColor: '#666',
    color: '#fff'
  }
});` where `sample7-1` is the class of div over which on hover this balloon will show up. **options** refers to possible options that you can give to balloon.

Comment: @krozaine Thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all the guys for helping me. Now I realized the problem is that I just referenced a jquery plugin, without referencing the real jquery. After I downloaded a jquery from http://jquery.com/download/, the problem solved.

```
<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.balloon.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           if(typeof jQuery !='undefined'){
              alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
           }else{
             alert("jQuery library is not found!");
           }
       </script>
<head>
```

Ps: The last script is very useful to check that whether jQuery library is loaded!